# Powershell - renaming folder with fixed characters in file name

Tags: powershell, directory, rename, wildcard

Apologies for this absolute noob question on PowerShell....

I am regularly downloading folders that always begin with a set of fixed characters at the start of the folder name, and a series of random numbers as a suffix. For example:

`NAME-1234`

What is the syntax for renaming these folders to something like 'temp' (as the new folder name).

So far I have tried:

`Get-ChildItem NAME-* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'NAME-*','temp' }`

But this just replaces 'NAME-' and I end up with 'temp1234'. When I just need the folders renamed to 'temp' without the suffixes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will probably give you a problem: what if a folder called `temp` already exists? It is the suffix that makes their names unique. Also, if all you want to rename are folders, at least add switch `-Directory` to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, otherwise you will also rename files.

Comment: Hi. There are no other folders or files in the directory, other than one folder called NAME-"suffix number".

Comment: If you can be sure no rename collisions can occur, then just try `Get-ChildItem -Filter 'NAME-*' -Directory | Rename-Item -NewName 'temp'`

Comment: Thanks Theo! Much appreciated and I will insert this into my main PowerShell script.